# How can variables use "~" for cd'ing?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, variable, cd-command

How can I use a variable - `$BASE` in my cd.
I tried the following but I get an error

```
$ cd ~/z/repo_1_ruby_193/
23:23:57 durrantm Castle2012 /home/durrantm/z/repo_1_ruby_193 

$ BASE="~/z"
23:24:03 durrantm Castle2012 /home/durrantm/z/repo_1_ruby_193 

$ cd $BASE/repo_1_ruby_193
-bash: cd: ~/z/repo_1_ruby_193: No such file or directory
23:24:25 durrantm Castle2012 /home/durrantm/z/repo_1_ruby_193
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In `cd ~/z/` you are using [Tilde expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01) to expand `~` into your home directory. In `BASE="~/z"`, you are not because you quoted the `~` character, so it is not expanded. That is why you get a message complaining about a nonexistent `~` directory. The solution is to not quote it, i.e. `BASE=~/z` in order to let the expansion occur.

Answer (score 11):

@jw013 has given a valid explanation and solution.

But there may be some cases when you do want to quote the paths, e.g. when they contain multiple spaces or special symbols. In this case you should use `$HOME` instead of `~`, i.e. your `BASE="~/z"` will become `BASE="$HOME/z"` and work correctly, because parameter substitution is interpreted in double quotes, unlike tilde expansion.

Comment: That's one way to do it, but it is not necessary. `BASE=~/"quoted name"` works just fine, so long as the `~` is left unquoted.

Comment: @hvd: you actually have to leave the slash unquoted as well. `BASE=~/"quoted name"` works, but `BASE=~"/quoted name"` doesn't.

Comment: You're right. Good catch.